# unity : undo to remove two objects that reference each other

Tags: unity3d-editor

i have a problem.

```
Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(a.gameobject);
Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(b.gameobject);
```

Above, 'a', it contains a field to refer to 'b'. Similarly, 'b' has a field to refer to 'a'.

When you undo after running the above code, the 'missing' generation in the fields of 'b'.

How should I handle this problem?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, your issue that you can't recreate the object 'b' because the 'a' reference is empty. If this is the case, you can use "GameObject.Find" however this can be a slow operation. Another solution is making prefabs and reference them... But again, this isn't a clean solution.